# z-standardization based on varying age ranges from the control group

Tags: r

I have a patient group (Group = 0) and a healthy control subject group (Group = 0). I have variables ID, Age, and C1. I want to z-standardize each individual C1 value in the patient group, using the corresponding C1 mean and standard deviation from the healthy control subject group within the age range matching each respective patient (plus or minus 5 years of the respective patient). Can someone help me with how to do this in R?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.